# Запрет доступа файлам одного пакета к файлам другого пакета

Tags: android, access, package

Здравствуйте, в ходе разработки приложения под андроид возникла следующая проблема:

имеются java файлы которые предназначены для реализации логики для подключения к устройству **типа1** они лежат в package **Device1** (внутри этого пакета находятся также подпакеты), другие java файлы лежат в package **Device2**.

В каждом пакете (**Device1**, **Device2**) имеются java файлы с одинаковым названием например **Func**. Пакеты **Device1**, **Device2** должны работать не зависимо друг от друга. Т.е. файлы пакета **Device1** не могут ссылаться на **Func** из пакета **Device2** и наоборот.

Также есть еще пакет **CommonConnection**, который реализует первоначальное подключение к пакетам **Device1**, **Device2**. В этом случае пакет **CommonConnection** должен иметь доступ ко все остальным пакетам и **Device1** и **Device2**.

Можно ли как-то запретить файлам из пакета **Device1** ссылаться на файлы из пакета **Device2** и наоборот, чтобы по ошибке при вводе автодополнения не ввести файл из чужого пакета, при этом чтобы общий пакет **CommonConnection** имел доступ и к файлам пакета **Device1** и к файлам **Device2** ?

Заранее благодарю всех за ответы.

---

Создал модули **Device1, Device2, CommonConnection**.
В build.gradle для **CommonConnection** ввел зависимости  для
**Device1, Device2** в итоге получил ошибку.

[image: Ошибка при вводе зависимости]

---

**Резюмирую здесь решение моей задачи, возможно кому-то пригодиться в будущем:**

1) Создаем 3 моудля **CommonConnection, Device1, Device2**. Нам необходимо, чтобы файлы в **CommonConnection** имели доступ в **Device1, Device2**. А **Device1, Device2** были изолированы друг от друга, т.е. файл из **Device1** не мог иметь доступ в **Device2**.
2) После создания модулей необходимо зайти в gradle для **Device1** и внести следующие изменения:

```
    **apply plugin: 'com.android.application'**
```

изменить на
         **apply plugin: 'com.android.library'**

И в **defaultConfig** убрать строку 
        **applicationId "com.bignerdranch.android.Device1"**

[image: В результате должно получиться]

3) Для **Device2** нужно сделать тоже самое. 
4) В gradle файле для **CommonConnection** нужно добавить строку
**compile project(':Device1')**

[image: в результате должно получиться]

5) Далее нужно явно указать что нужно запускать первоначально именно активити модуля **CommonConnection**. Нажимаем на **Select Run/Debug Configuration** и выбираем модуль **CommonConnection**. Далее еще раз нажимаем на **Select Run/Debug Configuration -> EditConfigurations.. ** в меню **Launch Options** в строке **Activity** жмем на **...** и выбираем активити для **CommonConnection**
в частности **MainActivityCommonConnection**.

[image: в результате должно получиться]

6) Теперь можно запустить проект и проверить.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну просто не делайте эти классы `public` и они будут видны только в рамках пакета. А лучше вынесите эти пакеты в разные модули проекта.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Дело в том что у меня еще есть пакет назовем его **"CommonConnection"**. Для реализации первоначальной логики соединения к устройству **типа1**, или **типа2** (соответственно вызываются пакеты либо **Device1**, либо **Device2**). Можно ли как то обеспечить пакету или модулю **CommonConnection**  доступ ко всем пакетам (модулям) **Device1**, **Device2**, а доступ пакета **Device1** к **Device2** (и обратно) запретить ?                                                                                       Вопрос в основной ветке переформулировал

Comment: просто добавляете Device1 и Device2 в зависимости модуля CommonConnection, а у них в зависимостях друг друга не добавляете и всё)

Comment: Спасибо. Ни могли бы вы описать как нужно добавить зависимости в gradle, если к примеру вместо пакетов мы теперь имеем модули **CommonConnection**, ** Device1**, ** Device2**. Т.е. чтобы к примеру при запуске проекта сначала запускался модуль **CommonConnection**. Затем он мог запустить модуль **Device1** или **Device2**. А модули **Device1** и **Device2** работали независимо друг от друга т.е. не имели доступ к файлам чужого модуля. Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: Модули подключаются так же как и библиотеки в секции `dependencies` просто пишете `compile project(':Device1')` например. Если у вас этот модуль не в корневой папке, а скажем в подпапке modules, то тогда будет `compile project(':modules:Device1')`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Попробовал сделать в экспериментальном проекте то ,что вы написали в итоге у меня возникла ошибка (вставил скриншот в основной вопрос). Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю ни так ? И будет ли у меня запускаться первоначально   "CommonConnection", потому что когда запускал проект до введение зависимостей у меня запускался **Device2**, а не "CommonConnection" ?

Comment: У вас должен быть только один модуль - приложение, остальные модули должны быть библиотеками и просто быть в зависимостях модуля приложения что он мог использовать их функционал. Просто измените в build.gradle скриптах для **Device1** и **Device2** применение плагина `com.android.application` на `com.android.library`. Ну и для запуска выбирайте CommonConnection.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Смена **application** на **library** помогло. Все заработало, теперь к примеру я могу из модуля **CommonConnection** ссылаться на классы из модуля **Device1**.  Теперь другая проблема: после введения **compile project(':Device1')** в build.gradle для модуля **CommonConnection**, основное активити для   **CommonConnection** перестало запускаться, вместо него сразу запускается основное активити  для **Device1**. Хотя в android studio в **Select run/debug configuration** я явно указываю, запускать модуль **CommonConnection**. Подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему ?

Comment: Так у вас должна быть только одна основная активити, разве что вы хотите иметь несколько ярлыков запуска для приложения, проверьте какая активити указана в конфигурации запуска для CommonConnection

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо. После **явного** указания в конфигурации (**Select run/debug configuration**) для CommonConnection какое активити запускать, все заработало.